# Route with name "course" not found, zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I can't solve this problem... I'm new in zend and this is a modified example from [zend](http://www.zendframework.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)

> Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException File: C:\wamp\www\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack.php:317 
>   Message: 
>   Route with name "course" not found

this is my module.config.php

```
<?php 

return array(
 'controllers' => array(
      'invokables' => array(
         'Course\Controller\Index' => 'Course\Controller\IndexController',
        ),  ),
    'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
           'index' => array(
                 'type' => 'Literal',
                     'options' => array(
                     'route' => '/course',
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Course\Controller\Index',
                         'action'     => 'index'
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         )
     ),
                'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'course' => __DIR__ . '/../view/'
     ),
     )


 );
```

and IndexController.php

```
    <?php 

namespace Course\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController{   

    protected $courseTable;


public function indexAction()
    {
     return new ViewModel(array(
             'courses' => $this->getCourseTable()->fetchAll(),
         ));
    }

    public function getCourseTable()
     {
         if (!$this->courseTable) {
             $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
             $this->courseTable = $sm->get('Course\Model\CourseTable');
         }
         return $this->courseTable;
     }
}
```

guys please help me, because I don't have any idea of what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 3):

Your config defines one route, called *index*. If you want it to be called 'course', you need to rename it. I've highlighted the route name in your config:

```
'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
       'index' => array( // <-- this array key is the route name
             'type' => 'Literal',
                 'options' => array(
                 'route' => '/course',
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Course\Controller\Index',
                     'action'     => 'index'
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     )
 ),
```

Comment: but when i rename it, then i see this error: 
 Fatal error: Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException: Route with name "index" not found in C:\wamp\www\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper.php on line 169

so if you can tell me more about it, i will be grateful

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to the route by two different names in your view. You need to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Problem for me was that I didn't register newly created module in /config/modules.config.php